# Compass Sprites Throwing Errors When Compiling

Tags: sass, css-sprites, compass

When compiling my css in compass with a sprite, I get the following errors:

> error scss/app.scss (Line 107 of icons/*.png: Mixin sprites doesn't have an argument named $separator.)

The funny thing is, the sprite image is being made, but the css is throwing the error. I set up following [Foundation's instructions](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html#cli).

Below is my setup.

**code in app.scss:**

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icons/*.png";
@include all-icons-sprites;
```

**Folder Structure**

```
+ www
  + sass
    - app.scss
  + images
    + icons
      - thumbsup.png
  + config.rb
```

**config.rb**

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
```

Thanks in advance!

Jay